# Docker AWS ECS Maximum policy size

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm new to docker/aws demployment and trying to get my own docker container which is working locally and described via docker-compose.yaml along with a Dockerfile to AWS.
I managed to get the CLI running but got somehow lost within the overhelming documentation on the AWS side. From what I understood it needs some kind of continuous integration with access to our source code. While this is not the main issue I would prefer just to deploy our pre build images. Here for I found in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/) and chapter describing the procedure.

The problem is, that the required AIM permissions are not in the JSON format at first, and secondly a similar set represented in JSON which can be found [here](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/docker-for-aws/iam-permissions/) get reported by AWS as exceeding Maximum policy size. The solution for that seam to be a manual quota increase request, but I don't know which quota exactly needs to be increased nor how to do it. Is it really such an uncommon use case to deploy directly from docker to AWS?

Thanks for all suggestions for a Docker/AWS newbie.

UPDATE:
I manage to upload finally an image by following this [tutorial](https://devops4solutions.com/deploy-docker-container-in-ecs-using-docker-compose/)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the article
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/ for transitioning from docker compose to ECS.
For IAM json limit follow the below blog https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-increase-policy-size/

Comment: I found the article you mention as well, and tried to follow it, but the AWS page for submitting quotas requests leads a vague page, where it's not clear how to proceed and what to ask for exactly. Also I don't understand, why using docker compose in AWS seam to be such an extraordinary story, that it requires manual unclear request submissions ‍♂️

Comment: It's not docker compose which need quota increase, it is the policy character limit which needs it

Comment: thx, and is there a simple clear way to increase the policy character limit?

Comment: this article has the mechanism like creating iam groups and attaching policy to them or creating multiple policies and attaching to the iam role.  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-increase-policy-size/

Comment: I don't understand the article at all ‍♂️ what does the 20 stands for? Why does the font size play any role in a JSON file? Sorry, but to me the article is more confusing than helping out.

Comment: 20 is the max number of managed iam policy you can attach to an iam role and 6,144 is the character limit when you are defining a managed iam policy. If you have a big iam policy break it up in multiple policies. Then attach to the role.